# Error on updating a datasource using DNN TextEditor field bound to the Text property

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik, dotnetnuke

If when binding to a TextEditor I use this syntax:

```
Text='<%# Bind("DESCRIPTION") %>'
```

I get the following error upon submitting the form:

```
InnerMessage:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
InnerStackTrace:
   at DotNetNuke.UI.UserControls.TextEditor.get_Text()
   at ASP.desktopmodules_mymodule_view_ascx.__ExtractValues__control16(Control __container)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.GridTemplateColumn.FillValues(IDictionary newValues, GridEditableItem editableItem)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.GridEditableItem.ExtractValues(IDictionary newValues)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.ExtractValuesFromItem(IDictionary newValues, GridEditableItem editedItem)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemBuilder.CreateItems(GridGroupingContext group)
```

It seems that calling the Text property getter is failing within the databinding layer.

If I replace the call to bind with Eval:

```
Text='<%# Eval("DESCRIPTION") %>'
```

Then the submit ignores the field of course, but I can catch the datasource updating property and get the text out of the text property manually and put it on the entity.  The Text property getter does not throw an error for me.

Why won't binding work automatically?  Note, this TextEditor is within a EditItemTemplate of a DnnGrid.  I'm not sure if that's related - I've not tried binding to one outside of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Text" "Content" or "Html" I do not remember which one it is, but one of those should work.

Comment: It has neither.  The RadEditor from Telerik has "Content", which works wonderfully.  Unfortunately they didn't just inherit from Telerik like with the other controls, because you can choose your rich text editor provider - which interestingly is most likely what's causing the null reference exception.  Source to the TextEditor [here](http://cs-dotnetnuke.googlecode.com/svn/tags/v4.3.6/CS_Library/DotNetNuke/UI/UserControls/TextEditor.ascx.cs).